# Python: "expected indent block" dont know how to fix

Tags: python

Ok, so I have my program but I'm getting an "expected an indent block" and i don't know where it is I believe I have it right but I'm very confused.

```
##Cave fuction
def cave():

    global lvl
    global mhp
    global exp

    while True:
        print("Who whould you like to talk to. (Emily(1), James(2), Paco(3)")
        talk = int(input("Who to talk to: "))
        ptint(" ")               
        if talk == 1:
            #put storie function here
        elif talk == 2:
            #put train function here
        elif talk == 3:
            print("Your level is", lvl, "you have", mhp, "and have", exp, "EXP")
        else:
            amsterdam = 7 #filler

        print("Anthing else needed(y/n)")
        ant = input("Anthing: ")

        if ant == n:
            break
        else:
            mexico = 19 #filler
```

Answer (score 2):

Put pass (or print statment or anything that executes really) between your if/elif statements. The comments aren't really read as code.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, there is no such thing as empty block like `{}` in C. If you want block to do nothing, you have to use `pass` keyword. For example:

```
if talk == 1:
    pass  # Put storie function here.
elif talk == 2:
    pass  # Put storie function here.
```

This should fix your problem. After line ending with `:`, next line MUST be intended, and comments do not count to indentation in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put some valid statements inside if-else statements, where you have written `put storie function here`. Following code will not throw an error as there is some valid statement for each if-else:

```
def cave():

    global lvl
    global mhp
    global exp

    while True:
        print("Who whould you like to talk to. (Emily(1), James(2), Paco(3)")
        talk = int(input("Who to talk to: "))
        ptint(" ")               
        if talk == 1:
            #put storie function here
            pass
        elif talk == 2:
            #put train function here
            pass
        elif talk == 3:
            print("Your level is", lvl, "you have", mhp, "and have", exp, "EXP")
        else:
            amsterdam = 7 #filler

        print("Anthing else needed(y/n)")
        ant = input("Anthing: ")

        if ant == n:
            break
        else:
            mexico = 19 #filler
```

Comment: ok i dident know that Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After the condition of `if` or `elif`, and after `else`, an indented block is expected. Something like this:

```
if condition:
    indented_block
elif condition:
    indented_block
else:
    indented_block
```

Just a comment as a block:

```
if condition:
    # ...
```

is not considered, so you have to put something there. One alternative is using a placeholder:

```
if condition:
    pass
```

`pass` is a null operation. When it is executed, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

if that's the exact code you're running, your problem should be within:

```
while True:
    print("Who whould you like to talk to. (Emily(1), James(2), Paco(3)")
    talk = int(input("Who to talk to: "))
    ptint(" ")               
    if talk == 1:
        #put storie function here
    elif talk == 2:
        #put train function here
```

here you get the comment `#put storie function here` which is not evaluated as code so basically what python interprets is:

```
while True:
    print("Who whould you like to talk to. (Emily(1), James(2), Paco(3)")
    talk = int(input("Who to talk to: "))
    ptint(" ")               
    if talk == 1:
    elif talk == 2:
    […]
```

whereas it expects:

```
while True:
    print("Who whould you like to talk to. (Emily(1), James(2), Paco(3)")
    talk = int(input("Who to talk to: "))
    ptint(" ")               
    if talk == 1:
        print("python wants actual code here in an inner block")
    elif talk == 2:
        print("python wants actual code here in an inner block as well")
    […]
```

and thus does not compile

Answer (score 0):

Your if blocks are empty. Try this

`if talk == 1:
        pass
        #put storie function here
    elif talk == 2:
        pass
        #put train function here
    elif talk == 3:
        print("Your level is", lvl, "you have", mhp, "and have", exp, "EXP")
    else:
        amsterdam = 7 #filler`

Answer (score 0):

you need to enter some statement before the.  `elif talk == 2:`

```
if talk == 1:
    print 1
elif talk == 2:
```